# In Maui .net, how to communicate with a usb device using android emulator?

Tags: c#, android-emulator, .net-6.0, maui, usbserial

I have a basic maui program in .net 6.0. I just started with .net and Maui. I want to communicate my android device eventually with an external device over usb .
For now, I want to debug using an android emulator (pixel device that visual studio provides)

How to do this ? Can I set up a virtual com port ? If so how should I do that?

Is there a sample program to communicate over usb in android on maui ?

I have tried using usb device list and trying to discover but that causes some problem while running for which I need to debug on the emulator to see where it’s going wrong.